# Why am I not getting if a class is present in a div?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following div:

```
<div class="row hide alert-danger text-center h4 alert" 
 id="test 123" data-for="862">
Some Text.
</div>
```

When I am writing this:`$('#test 123').hasClass('hide')`
I am still getting false.

Any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An ID should not contain spaces - this is part of html5 spec I believe

Comment: From HTML specification: **The ID value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per html4 as well as html5 standard, You can not have whitespace in it.

I do not encourage you to use this solution but you can use attribute equal selector as a workaround:

```
$('[id="test 123"]').hasClass('hide')
```

Comment: This is the most relevant answer for given requirement. +1

Comment: This is a good answer but you have to question why the ID has a space in it in the first place. From HTML spec: **The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.**

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
<div class="row hide alert-danger text-center h4 alert" 
 id="test-123" data-for="862">
Some Text.
</div>
```

And then `$('#test-123').hasClass('hide')` should work as expected.

jQuery things that the space designates the start of another selector. So it looks for an <123> element within your element with id #test

Answer (score 0):

The way your selector works now, is it is searching for 123 inside your div #test. Either change it to just test, or test_123.

Answer (score 0):

better approach of coding and we should follow the rules and convention of coding, we have to setup DOM element id without space, you need to change id to test_123(with out space)

Answer (score 0):

In CSS and jQuery selectors, a space is a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators). Your selector — `#test 123` — matches "Elements of the type `<123>` that are descendants of an element that has `id="test"`".

Additionally, [the HTML specification says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) (about ID attributes):

> The value must not contain any space characters.

So:

- Change your ID to a valid one
- Change the selector to match

Such:

```
id="test-123"

'#test-123'
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one:

```
<div class="row hide alert-danger text-center h4 alert" 
 id="test 123" data-for="862">
Some Text.
</div>
```

jquery

```
$( "#test 123" ).hasClass( "hide" )
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers! The same answer as yours has already been provided.